# bootstrap js files in chrome not loading for wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am completing a tutorial on how to convert a bootstrap template into a wordpress theme, when it comes to the js and css files I think it's been done right but when I open chrome F12 console, I get red messages like :

Uncaught TypeError: Browser.addMessageHandlers is not a function

GET http://127.0.0.1:4001/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js 
(index):121 GET http://127.0.0.1:4001/bootstrap/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js

but the outside link to jquery must be working.

Any advice would be awesome.

Comment: Show your code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try turning off Chrome's device mode ... do you still get the errors?

Comment: Hi Ted, I turned off the device mode and it got rid of the errors but I still get - GET http://127.0.0.1:4001/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js altogether 4 of them. Is this normal.